# New records since last query in MySQL View

Tags: mysql, view

I am looking for a way to create a View that when queried will automatically only retrieve new records since the last query. My tables have a timestamp field for all entries, so for a simple example I can

```
SELECT * WHERE timestamp >= 'blah'
```

but I don't know how to determine what `blah` should be from the last query. So if the View was queried at 11:00 and then again at 12:00, the query at 12:00 should only return records added since 11:00. And so on... This all needs to be accomplished in the View, the end user should simply be able to query the View and get the results.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Store last access date time in database per user persistent session
   table, if you have one. On next view call to database, use the
   previous latest access time in the session to filter rows starting
   from.
2. Store last access date time in user virtual session at client
   environment. On every call to server, send last access date time as
   well. So that server uses it to filter rows starting from.

I prefer to use second option that process won't write any data in database tables.

Comment: Not sure either of these are work in my case. I need the view to be self contained. The view is raw queried, pretty much just a `SELECT * FROM VIEW` I can't pass any data to it. I am not using any sort of server side scripting.

Comment: In the post you said, you can use a `where` clause. If so, you can implement one of the suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I can use the `where` clause within the View. The View will simply be called with a SELECT. I also said "I am looking for a way to create a View that when queried will **automatically** only retrieve new records since the last query." Your way requires the user/service doing the query to keep track of where they are and where to start the query from next. I want the View to do this. The end user should be able to query the view with a simple `SELECT` and the View take care of the rest. I was thinking the View could keep track somehow?

Comment: No. Predefined view can't help you. Your code module however needs to remember last access time so that it can retrieve records on next call. Without which it is not possible.

Comment: Is there no way to add an update statement in the View that records the last query timestamp in a table somewhere, which is read at the start of the View to tell it where to start?

Comment: My options in answer suggest similar. But every user will have his last access time different. Due to the reason changing view definition on every call is not good idea as there would exist multiple users accessing the same view at different timestamps.

Comment: I understand your concern, but the the View is only accessed by one user so the last access time will always be correct for that user.

Answer (score 0):

As there may be an unread record that slips through undetected (say it came less than a second since the last one accessed, so it has the same timestamp), set a column to auto increment (typically labelled `id`) and check for entries using it e.g. in PHP save the last accessed record in a $lastId variable, and use:

```
$sql="SELECT * WHERE `id` > '$lastId'";
```