# MySQL Query/View to pull only new data since last query

Tags: mysql, view

I would like to create a View that only returns new data added to the database since the last time the View was run. I know this sounds like a simple question, and there a millions of question just like it on here, but there are some restrictions in my case.

- I can't use Stored Procedures, Functions or Triggers.
- The user accessing the View only has read access to the database.

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096146/new-records-since-last-query-in-mysql-view) and was going to add an UPDATE statement to update a table with the current DateTime, and then check this table at the beginning of the View and only query after this DateTime. But the user accessing the View only has read access now.

I was also thinking there might be a type of timestamp column that updates to the current time when read with a SELECT statement, but apparently not.

Just for reference there is only ONE user accessing this view.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, whether it's possible at all. MySQL doesn't store, whether this record was returned or not last time. And as you can't write to the database, there is no way to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user only has read access to the database, then you have to store the relevant information at the application layer and not in the database.  It simply is not possible to store information in the database if you don't have write access -- or at least information not part of some other process.

The recommendation would be for the application to keep track of the record returned -- keeping track of the maximum `CreatedAt` value or `id`.  Then access the database using something like:

```
select v.*
from view v
where id > $id;
```

The subsequent code would update `$id` in the application.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately there is no application. The user is directly querying the view.